# C# Running concurrent requests using WebTestRequest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, testing, load-testing, coded-ui-tests

When writing coded web tests using the Web Performance Test API. Can you write test that send requests at the same time i.e. concurrent ones, that is with one user of the load test, fire off concurrent web requests?

edit: added extra information

I have found out that adding requests to the dependentRequest property of another request means the dependentRequests are ran concurrently. Aside: Why is the microsoft documentation around this feature so light?

Scenario 1: Let's say I have two web requests

```
public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
{
    var request1 = new WebTestRequest("request1Uri");
    var request2 = new WebTestRequest("request2Uri");

    yield return request1;
    yield return request2;
}
```

The above runs sequentially, If I want to run them(request1 and request2) simultaneously must I add a third request and run it like below, it works but wondering if there was a cleaner(without creating a third request) way? as the results are affected by adding a not needed request.

```
public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
{
    var request1 = new WebTestRequest("request1Uri");
    var request2 = new WebTestRequest("request2Uri");
    var request3 = new WebTestRequest("request3Uri");
    request3.DependentRequests.AddRange(new[] { request2, request1 });

    yield return request3;      
}
```

Scenario 2: From what I can see the dependent requests are just "one deep" by that I mean

```
public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
{
    var request1 = new WebTestRequest("request1Uri");
    var request2 = new WebTestRequest("request2Uri");
    var request3 = new WebTestRequest("request3Uri");
    var request4 = new WebTestRequest("request4Uri");
    var request5 = new WebTestRequest("request5Uri");

    request3.DependentRequests.AddRange(new[] { request2, request1 });
    request5.DependentRequests.AddRange(new[] { request4, request3 });

    yield return request5;      
}
```

is the same as

```
public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
{
    var request1 = new WebTestRequest("request1Uri");
    var request2 = new WebTestRequest("request2Uri");
    var request3 = new WebTestRequest("request3Uri");
    var request4 = new WebTestRequest("request4Uri");
    var request5 = new WebTestRequest("request5Uri");

    request5.DependentRequests.AddRange(new[] { request2, request1, request4, request3 });

    yield return request5;      
}
```

What if I want the first example's (in scenario 2) expected behaviour, how can I achieve this using the webTest api?

Comment: I believe that that is how dependant requests are processed. In a PreRequest plugin to a Web Performance Test you can add/delete dependant requests.

Comment: @AdrianHHH you are right, that is how dependent requests work, but if all you had were 2 request that had to be run simultaneously, would you then have to create a third 'fake' request, point it at say google.com and add the 2 'real' requests as dependent requests? what is the proper way to do write this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experiences. Using the dependent request property of the WebTestRequest is a way of getting requests to be made concurrently using microsoft's Web Performance Test API.

For scenario 1, I didn't find anything better than what's already in the question.

For scenario 2, I did something similar to the below to get close enough to the behaviour I wanted

```
public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
{
    var request1 = new WebTestRequest("request1Uri");
    var request2 = new WebTestRequest("request2Uri");
    var request3 = new WebTestRequest("request3Uri");
    var request4 = new WebTestRequest("request4Uri");
    var request5 = new WebTestRequest("request5Uri");
    var request6 = new WebTestRequest("request6Uri");

    request6.DependentRequests.AddRange(new[] { request2, request1 });
    request5.DependentRequests.AddRange(new[] { request4, request3 });

    yield return request5;      
    yield return request6;
}
```